# Slick slider change background-color on each slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

The setup is this.
A slider with client logos, showen one at a time.
I would like to change the background-color of my parent div to the specific brandcolor from each client(and the H1). animateded if possible.

How would i go about doing that?

My HTML - I would like to change the background-color of the section div and the h1 in the content-wrapper.

```
        <div class="section clients section-text-right">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <h1>Clients</h1>
            <div class="frontpage-client-slick slick-theme-frontpage">
                <div class="scouts"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_scouts@2x.png"></div>
                <div class="jjd"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_jjd_white@2x.png"></div>
                <div class="unipension"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_unipension@2x.png"></div>
                <div class="dr"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_dr@2x.png"></div>
                <div class="verdensborn"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_verdensboern@2x.png"></div>
                <div class="fi"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_fi@2x.png"></div>
                <div class="midtlink"><img src="images/client-logos/logo_midtlink@2x.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Slick slider - i know i need to do something in the beforeChange, i just dont know what.

```
$('.frontpage-client-slick').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    fade: true,
    centerMode: true
});
$('.frontpage-client-slick').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the slide elements and set the background color via jQuery and .css() for example.

The slick object stores it's slides in $slides so you can access them via the index provided through nextSlide.

I've created a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3jp35m/5/) for you:

```
var $slideContainter = $('.frontpage-client-slick'),
    $slider = $slideContainter.slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1000,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        fade: true,
        centerMode: true
    }),
    colorSettings = {
        headline: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow','red', 'blue', 'yellow','blue'],
        section: ['blue', 'yellow','red', 'blue', 'yellow','blue', 'red']
    },
    changeColors = function (slide) {
        $slideContainter.siblings('h1').animate({
        color: colorSettings.headline[slide]
    }, 1000 );

    $slideContainter.parentsUntil('.section').animate({
        backgroundColor: colorSettings.section[slide]
    }, 1000 );
    };

// Initial call to set color
changeColors(0);

$slider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    changeColors(nextSlide);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Forgive my ignorance, but im not looking for a random color. I need a very specifik color for each slide. so when the slide .scout is active, the background of .section changes to a specifc color. etc.

Comment: Hey just added the random color for the example. Where does the color information should come from? A class? If not and you would like to set the color inline via javascript just use $slideContainter.siblings('h1').css({color: '#000000'}); to set it to black e.g.

Comment: Updated the example code. Now you can set your colors two arrays. The index of the color expresses the slide number, starting with 0.

Comment: Color information will be hardcoded in the script. Something like _if active slide = .scout then background-color:#3b1f6a, H1:#ffffff_ and so on for each slide. Something i controll manually.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, that was exactly what i was looking for. I just edited the example to add animations :). Once again, thank you. You're awesome.